# #accordion is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

Got a problem with an accordion script, the accordion worked when I was working with it with straight html, but now having moved to wordpress the accordion has stopped working.

Here is my code

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
  });
  </script>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

and the html:

```
            <div id="accordion">
 <div class="button"><a href="#">Infrastructure</a></div>
    <div><?php
            if (function_exists('iinclude_page')){
                iinclude_page('sectors/infrastructure');
            }?>
            </div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#">Housing</a></div>
    <div><?php
            if (function_exists('iinclude_page')){
                iinclude_page('sectors/housing');
            }?></div>
                <div class="button"><a href="#">Education</a></div>
    <div><?php
            if (function_exists('iinclude_page')){
                iinclude_page('sectors/education');
            }?></div>
                <div class="button"><a href="#">Health</a></div>
    <div><?php
            if (function_exists('iinclude_page')){
                iinclude_page('sectors/health');
            }?></div>
</div>
```

I really do not understand the problem, as it worked in straight html. I have even tried removing the include function with straight text and it still doesn't work?

Any ideas? There are no other jquery objects interfearing either.

Comment: is there any difference between the html in your source code and the html you see when you do view source in the browser?  plugins that do optimization will try to squeeze out unnecessary line breaks.  if general always put an html comment within the empty tags (script or otherwise).

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898071/jquery-ui-typeerror-accordion-is-not-a-function?rq=1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're loading jQuery twice (1.5 followed by 1.7.1), and loading jQuery UI after loading 1.5 but before loading 1.7.1. So here's what happens:

1. jQuery 1.5 is loaded.
2. jQuery UI is loaded and attaches itself to the `jQuery` object that exists at that point.
3. jQuery 1.7.1 is loaded, completely replacing the `jQuery` object.
4. Your code runs, using the (1.7.1) `jQuery` object, which jQuery UI hasn't added its goodness to.

If you load jQuery just once, and make sure you load jQuery UI afterward, it'll work.

Comment: That's just what I meant to say ;) Thanks for the explanation of *why*.

Comment: Thankyou, this is so weird, because I copied and pasted the code from the jquery website itself on the accordion page which included the 2 versions in the code!

Comment: @Amy: Glad that helped! I don't see two versions of jQuery being loaded on [the accordion page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) at jqueryui.com.

Answer (score 2):

You're including jQuery twice, perhaps that's that problem?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
..
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me the full html when you run it on Wordpress.
I was thinking that maybe in the include pages there are some unclosed tags that could corrupt the accordion.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And try to do not insert jQuery twice.

Comment: He has a point, since this runs fine without the php tags : http://jsfiddle.net/zd6Hg/

Comment: @gideon I've done the same check :-) http://jsfiddle.net/JF8WY/
But I want to see the html with Wordpress includes

Comment: ah. Yea I wondered why someone -1'd since this was very valid, so I +1 :)