# jQuery UI: TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

For some reason the **jQuery UI Accordion** does not work. I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function

What am i doing wrong? Based on other answers on this site on similar topics, i think it has something to do with the included files.

My header includes are:

```
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">  

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/base_con.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/skeleton.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/layout.css">

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/responsiveslides.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Does your custom jqueryui actually include the accordion plugin?

Comment: Make sure the path to your jQuery core file and jQuery UI file are correct. Have a look in Firebug or some other console tool to make sure thay are loading.

Comment: thanks Richard, fixed it :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This problem could arise from a couple of different things:

- You are not including jQuery UI library.
- You are including jQuery UI library above the inclusion of jQuery library
- The path to jQuery UI and jQuery libraries might be incorrect
- You are using a custom jQuery UI library that does not have an accordion

Since the first two do not apply to you, I would recommend triple-checking the path and using a full jQuery UI library instead of the custom one:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the jQuery UI library had to be included after the jQuery one.

Answer (score 9):

Using two `jquery.js` files may cause a conflict and result in an errorbeing thrown. Avoid importing two or more `jquery.js` files.

Comment: Thank you for adding this - was my problem. Silly mistake - but I was looking for the wrong thing before you noted this.

Answer (score 1):

in your last code lines, include the script in below order :-

There is no need to include the below as it will be taken care by above scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the js files matters!

```
/external/jquery/jquery.js should be listed above jquery-ui.js!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a WordPress website. I added it in the header.
Use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).